# Titanium Developer

Tags: ios-simulator, android-emulator, titanium

I am trying to use the titanium developer v.1.2.1 but i have some difficulty the simulators are not lunching!
for the iPhone simulator nothing happens it just goes like this and the simulator is not shown

```
[INFO] Compiling JavaScript...one moment
[INFO] No JavaScript errors detected.
[INFO] One moment, building ...
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 1.4.1.1
[INFO] iPhone Device family: iphone
[INFO] iPhone SDK version: 3.1
```

And for the Android ti says

```
[INFO] Launching Android emulator...one moment
[INFO] Building HelloWorld for Android ... one moment
[INFO] Waiting for the Android Emulator to become available
[INFO] Copying project resources..
[INFO] Tiapp.xml unchanged, skipping class generation
[INFO] Manifest unchanged, skipping Java build
[ERROR] /Users/vladimirrobevski/Desktop/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/apkbuilder
[INFO] Installing application on device
[ERROR] Failed installing com.devoncompanyinc.helloworld: pkg: /data/local/tmp/app.apk
```

Is someone having the same problem?How to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear if you are trying to run the app in the simulator or the phone. I'll assume for iphone, you are talking simulator.

I have had this same problem before with iphone (but not android) along with other build issues like this.  Here's what I did to get it to work:

1. Delete the contents of the iphone build folder (as described in other answer).
2. Assuming you are on a mac, open project in XCode and build from there.
3. Run simulator from xcode...you can connect your phone and run on phone from there,
   too.
4. If the simulator doesn't work from here, you'll need to update your xcode tools. If it works, go to next step.
5. Launch Titanium developer and run the
   project again. It should launch in the simulator.

Comment: sorry i have given up from that thing months ago

Answer (score 0):

what I usually do is delete the all of the files in the build/iphone directory... **just the files NOT the directories** and that should force a complete rebuild of the project

Comment: no result it only rebuilds the files and still nothing happens and what about the android emulator??

Comment: @Spire sometimes you need to kickstart the emulator by launching it manually for android. For iPhone include the whole log... more information is needed to assist you